# ArcGIS Online HTML popup: Why does the code for the table background colors keep getting removed?

Tags: arcgis-online, html, html-popup

I have the following code as my popup

```
<table style= "background-color:#E1E1E1">
<tbody>
<tr><td colspan="2" style= "background-color:#3C4859"> <b> <font color = "#FFFFFF">{counties_NAME}</font></b></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"> <b> Income spent on Housing &amp; Transportation...</b> </td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr> <td style= "background-color:#FFFFFF" height="15" width="15"> </td></tr>
<tr> <td style= "background-color:#FFC171" height="15" width="15"> </td></tr>
<tr> <td style= "background-color:#FD7155" height="15" width="15"> </td></tr>
<tr> <td style= "background-color:#E94749" height="15" width="15"> </td></tr>
<tr> <td style= "background-color:#C03351" height="15" width="15"> </td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
<td width="250"><font color="{expression/expr0}" size="9">{ht_index_data_v3_csv_ht_ami}%</font></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

It works fine for a while, but then all the background colors will disappear. The code then looks like this without me changing anything.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td colspan="2"> <b> <font>{counties_NAME}</font></b></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"> <b> Income spent on Housing &amp; Transportation...</b> </td></tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr> <td height="15" width="15"> </td></tr>
<tr> <td height="15" width="15"> </td></tr>
<tr> <td height="15" width="15"> </td></tr>
<tr> <td height="15" width="15"> </td></tr>
<tr> <td height="15" width="15"> </td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
<td width="250"><font color="{expression/expr0}" size="9">{ht_index_data_v3_csv_ht_ami}%</font></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

ArcGIS online is removing the style portions of my code and I'm not sure why. Online, it says it's supported.